# aracne in R using minet package

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am trying to  learn ARACNE  in R using minet package for the first time but I am unable to start anything since I don't have the input dataset file. Below is what mentioned according to minet manual

```
build.mim(dataset, estimator = "spearman", 
                   disc = "none", nbins = sqrt(NROW(dataset)))
```

Where can I get this sample input dataset file? And, how to start executing the program step by step starting from the scratch. Is there any video tutorials available to learn for a first timer like me?

Comment: `data(syn.data) ; build.mim(syn.data, estimator = "spearman", disc = "none", nbins = sqrt(NROW(syn.data)))`. You could have found this data set  in the example section of `help("build.mim")`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Can it be loaded from the external .csv file?. Is it available from public domain website like GEO. If so what does rows and columns represents in that file contains. I have never seen the expression datasets file. Can you please provide me the sample datasets file if any

Comment: You could just type `data(syn.data) ; print(syn.data)`